# Drupal 7 multisite setup white screen

Tags: 7, multi-sites, debugging, wsod

I have attempted to set up a Drupal 7 multi site set-up. I followed the instructions online and have one site (site1) that is setup like a regular single install Drupal site and a second site (site2) set up in the sites/sites2 directory. The sites use separate databases.

The issue I am having is that while site1 displays and operates normally, site2 only displays a white screen. When I executed the install.php script for site2, everything seemed to go normally until I actually try to view the site. Any ideas as to what the issue could be? I am sure that settings.php file in both installations is set up correctly so I am a bit lost.

Thanks.

Comment: WSODs are thoroughly covered on Drupal.org - read [article about fixing them](https://drupal.org/node/482956) and if it will not be enough, provide data you collected in 1a and 2b steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to tell you exactly what is wrong with the information that is given.  I run several multi-sites using separate databases, and they work as advertised when I set them up following the standard instructions.

The White Screen of Death is usually caused by some error in the PHP.  To see the error message, you need to turn on PHP error reporting.  To do this, add the following to the `settings.php`, just below the initial `<?php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

This will usually show an error message that tells you where you've left out a semicolon or some other trivial PHP-error.

See also: https://drupal.org/node/1056468 and https://drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: Thanks, that helped identify the issue! In my case it was a library file being used on site1 that was throwing an exception when site2 was trying to use it. I now have something to investigate.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out trying to find a decent error message - tried pasting these php settings in several places but what ultimately worked for me was vising subsite.yourdomain.com/update.php and seeing which modules I was missing.